# Python Requests and clicking a button

Tags: python, python-requests

So I know you can't like actually click the button like selenium. However, I want to use python requests for the program that I'm coding. The way I see it that when you want to click a button you basically submit a request to the server to click and add to the watch list (using eBay as an example). I assume you have to use the POST for that. However when I try to find the POST URL for a listing such as this

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rockville-HTS56-1000w-5-1-Channel-Home-Theater-System-Bluetooth-USB-8-Subwoofer/302495341359?_trkparms=pageci%3Ac45ae602-b2bb-11e8-91a9-74dbd1807185%7Cparentrq%3Ab4e1b5ee1650a9ccac0001e5fffeeebd%7Ciid%3A1

I can't find a POST request  when I check the Network tab in dev tools. I only see GET requests. Am I doing something wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find a POST request when I check the Network tab in dev tools. I only see GET requests. Am I doing something wrong???

No, just you can't see POST requests because the data you send is passed as query string, it means that data is *encoded in the url*.

If you open Dev Tools and click on the first request once you have clicked the button (or even a link), you can go to **params** section and get all the data you sent.

Using the requests module the form data in sent with the *data* keyword with a POST request, while the parameters that are encoded in the url are passed to the *params* keyword with both GET and POST methods.

for example, this is exactly the request I made when I added the item to the watch list:

```py
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/myb'

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.ebay.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko'
    '/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q='
    '0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rockville-HTS56-1000w-5-1-Channel-'
        'Home-Theater-System-Bluetooth-USB-8-Subwoofer/302495341359?_trkpar'
        'ms=pageci%3Ac45ae602-b2bb-11e8-91a9-74dbd1807185%7Cparentrq%3Ab4e1'
    'b5ee1650a9ccac0001e5fffeeebd%7Ciid%3A1',
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=6E3675DDC01917342E915A485425DE14; ebay=%5Ecv%3D15'
        '555%5Esbf%3D%2310000100000%5Epsi%3DATBv5t4c*%5Ejs%3D1%5E; dp1=bu1p'
        '/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**5d73f732^bl/IT5f552ab2^pbf/#800080000080000000000'
        '05f552ac5^; s=CgAD4ACBblBUyYjU0YzFiZjkxNjUwYTk5Yjc4NzAzZjhhZmZjNjJ'
        'iNjClGshN; nonsession=CgAAIABxbulCyMTUzNjM0NDk4OHgzMDI0OTUzNDEzNTl'
        '4MHgyTgDKACBk+MUyYjU0YzFiZjkxNjUwYTk5Yjc4NzAzZjhhZmZjNjJiNjAAywABW'
        '5LK0jZ87uR5; ak_bmsc=CBC404CFCC021D437EAEB56AB0A505C80212FF677D1B0'
        '0009DC3925B8422CF41~pl1XkGGUVkQmdzLfSzxOHqS7a6B5bt6IE+YZ9pBQsojU23'
        '4gAkOREldw07haa9wqBjRKkfaGqXnWck+XkoiOMH75VNvp7RX0Tswwmgd2XI2DLpTf'
        'Z3Wic4ULyIjHQiolAXprZboWAssr45zCzbT1DEfphZ+3vHtD2sZcfcIUj/u5hrbWmX'
        'WcqZHABtvn/XDI5z8ul1rnRe0ZM87TfkySxS09SXR1c+HoE8BVBm0WeSB6o=; npii'
        '=btguid/b54c1bf91650a99b78703f8affc62b605d73f72e^cguid/b54c2316165'
        '0ac3c480165a5fe7d7b1e5d73f72e^; cssg=b54c1bf91650a99b78703f8affc62'
        'b60; bm_sv=43E32CFCCEEB3DE24A7853BCD296554D~5g3PXHhS+OOCPoJYdO/hGo'
        'GEWmrSON6AvaW8RYaPM31Yhe4afGf1MM/OmSgHoFPrTLloRcPphW1KrOy4IjnUiiHU'
        'BHq60fazRhTC9rdF6bweXE9Oyz02T4zoySTDLYfL8SJtb99/tNa5v1jarB5cjA==; '
        'AMCV_A71B5B5B54F607AB0A4C98A2%40AdobeOrg=-1758798782%7CMCIDTS%7C17'
        '782%7CMCMID%7C80964471016865310950758990401017778531%7CMCAID%7CNON'
        'E%7CMCOPTOUT-1536352227s%7CNONE; AMCVS_A71B5B5B54F607AB0A4C98A2%40'
    'AdobeOrg=1; ds2=sotr/b7pwxzzzzzzz^',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'DNT': '1',
}

params = {
    '_trksid:p2047675.l1359',
    'SubmitAction.AddToListVI': 'x',
    'item': '302495341359',
    'rt': 'nc',
    'srt': '0100030000005006d271d47b3a0557eff3cbcd450ad13d38dd94ca9e'\
        '2d8918de753cf5a1dfc6eeb0648b5e9c433cbf106609c6d81bed4ad1fa6'\
        'fa0fdbeca4bc2e3ae88a523453c4a5620551f91a45384f9d5a4054f8e56',
    'etn': 'Watch list',
    'tagId': '-99',
    'wt': 'f1cc17761369fcda30b0792ff44e1a09',
    'ssPageName': 'VIP:watchlink:top:en',
    'sourcePage': '4340',
}

requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

[EDIT 1]

Working code example to scrape "Add to watch list" button:

```py
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rockville-HTS56-1000w-5-1-Cha'\
      'nnel-Home-Theater-System-Bluetooth-USB-8-Subwoofer/302'\
      '495341359?_trkparms=pageci%3Ac45ae602-b2bb-11e8-91a9-7'\
      '4dbd1807185%7Cparentrq%3Ab4e1b5ee1650a9ccac0001e5fffee'\
      'ebd%7Ciid%3A1'


def get_watch_list_url(page_source):
    """
    Return "Add to watch list" button url.
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
    for button in soup.find_all('a'):
        if button.get_text() == 'Add to watch list':
            return button.get('href')


def main():
    with Session() as session:

        response = session.get(url) # visit item page and scrape button
        add_to_watch_list_url = get_watch_list_url(response.text)

        print('Url is:', add_to_watch_list_url)

        response = session.get(add_to_watch_list_url) # add item to watch list

        if response.ok:
            print('Item successfully added to watch list')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[EDIT 2]

Example of implementation with `aiohttp`:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/Rockville-HTS56-1000w-5-1-Cha'\
      'nnel-Home-Theater-System-Bluetooth-USB-8-Subwoofer/302'\
      '495341359?_trkparms=pageci%3Ac45ae602-b2bb-11e8-91a9-7'\
      '4dbd1807185%7Cparentrq%3Ab4e1b5ee1650a9ccac0001e5fffee'\
      'ebd%7Ciid%3A1'    

def get_watch_list_url(page_source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
    for button in soup.find_all('a'):
        if button.get_text() == 'Add to watch list':
            return button.get('href')


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        # Send request and get response.
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            html = await response.text()

        # Extract button url.
        add_to_watch_list_url = get_watch_list_url(html)

        # Add item to watch list.
        async with session.get(add_to_watch_list_url) as response:
            status = response.status

        print('Request status code:', status) # print the request status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: So how would I add to watch list? I assume that it is safe to say that for every item the add to watch list won't be the same

Comment: Well, we have to understand how params change in relation to the item you desire. Another solution could be scrape the button with _BeautifulSoup_ or with _re_.

Comment: Mhh. I've just given a look to the page html source. Personally, I think it's faster to scrape the url with re. I'll write a script to do it and include it in the answer as soon as possible. Glad to help you!

Comment: Done! Now, whenever you get an item page, the script will automatically get the "Add to watch list" button. If you need anything else, you can also send me an email to the address you find in my profile.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code. How would the code be is I used aiohttp instead?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check the page with the button to determine what type of request it is making. Look at the surrounding `<form>` element. If it has a `method` attribute, then you can see whether the form is doing a POST or a GET. If it doesn't have a `method`, then it defaults to POST. You will also see the exact URL in the `form`'s `action` attribute. You can scrape all of this with beautifulsoup and then use requests to make the request.